# Excel VBA: Giving array values as 'for loop' limits

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, syntax-error

I am facing 'Compile error: Syntax error' when I run the following code:

c_bound_h() is an array with indices from 0 to j. Lets assume the value of j is 3 (for this example) and the values in it are given below. The data in the sheet's rows is sorted according to these limits. e.g from row2 till row1507 = 'Value 1', row 1508 till row3013 = 'Value 2', and so on.

I want to loop through each class of data, by passing these limits in the For loop. But, it is giving syntax error.

```
j = 3

c_bound_h(0) = 2
c_bound_h(1) = 1508
c_bound_h(2) = 3014
c_bound_h(3) = 4519
```

'I want to loop through each class of data, by passing these limits in the For loop. But, it is giving syntax error.

```
For L = 0 To j

    For c_bound_h(L) To c_bound_h(L+1)-1

Next L
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify code as follows:

```
For L = 0 To j

    For K= c_bound_h(L) To c_bound_h(L+1)-1
    Next K

Next L
```

Answer (score 0):

Use For L = 1 to J-1....

Because c_bound_h(L+1) would otherwise be out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring c_bound_h as an integer?

I put this code into a workbook and it works perfectly fine for me :-

```
Sub test()

j = 3

Dim c_bound_h(4) As Integer

c_bound_h(0) = 2
c_bound_h(1) = 1508
c_bound_h(2) = 3014
c_bound_h(3) = 4519


For L = 0 To j

    For k = c_bound_h(L) To c_bound_h(L + 1) - 1
        MsgBox ("pass")
    Next k

Next L



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to prevent unneccessary loops by comparing 2 values at a time, but not going over the array limits. This is based on 'Don Relentless' code, but modified slightly.

```
Sub test()

j = 3

Dim c_bound_h(0 to 3) As Integer

c_bound_h(0) = 2
c_bound_h(1) = 1508
c_bound_h(2) = 3014
c_bound_h(3) = 4519

For L = 1 To j

    For k = c_bound_h(L-1) To c_bound_h(L) - 1
        debug.print "pass row " & k
    Next k

Next L

End Sub
```